# bash search for string in each line of file

Tags: bash, string, file-io

I'm trying what seems like a very simple task: use bash to search a file for strings, and if they exist, output those to another file. It could be jetlag, but this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

cnty=CNTRY

for line in $(cat wheatvrice.csv); do
    if [[ $line = *$cnty* ]]
    then
        echo $line >> wr_imp.csv
    fi
done
```

I also tried this for completeness:

```
#!/bin/bash

cnty=CNTRY

for line in $(cat wheatvrice.csv); do
    case $line in 
    *"$cnty"*) echo $line >> wr_imp.csv;;
    *) echo "no";;
    esac
done
```

both output everything, regardless of whether the line contains CNTRY or not, and I'm copy/pasting from seemingly reliable sources, so apparently there's something simple about bash-ness that I'm missing?

Comment: for what it's worth, some lines are: <br>Brazil,CNTRY-average,1989.428053,0.875353691,2899.968733,531.652993 <br> these are the ones i want, and others are <br> Cambodia,Pouthisat,,,3857.124865,122.266868 <br> and these are not the ones I want

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Don't use bash, use grep.

```
grep -F "$cnty" wheatvrice.csv >> wr_imp.csv
```

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something but that seems to have the same effect both w/in the bash script and just directly in the terminal.

Comment: using grep -F "$cnty" wheatvrice.csv >> wr_imp.csv simply puts every line from wheatvrice.csv into wr_imp.csv

Comment: Do you actually *have* anything in `$cnty`?

Comment: He sets it to `CNTRY`, maybe you should just use that explicitly.

Comment: Im' really sorry, this is just me being sleepy & having Excel (aka my least favorite program ever) put the wrong line endings on. Upvoted & thanks.

Comment: Somehow this conversation made me LOL :)

Answer (score 4):

While I would suggest to simply use grep too, the question is open, why you approach didn't work. Here a self referential modification of your second approach - with keyword 'bash' to match itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

cnty=bash    
while read -r line
do
    case $line in 
        *${cnty}*) 
            echo $line " yes" >> bashgrep.log
            ;;
        *)
                echo "no"
                ;;
    esac
done < bashgrep.sh
```

The keypoint is `while read -r line ... < FILE`. Your command with cat involves String splitting, so every single word is processed in the loop, not every line.

The same problem in example 1.