# Search within a file using Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, search, ksh

I have a file which has 25 lines of data in the format

```
Sl.No|ID|NAME|CITY|ZIP
1|4524|John Blake|New York|11505
```

How can I search for a specific ID in that file and print that line using Shell scripting?

Please note that I want to search in the second column only.
If I use grep, it will search the whole line. I want to search only for the ID

This is working
awk '$1 ~/4524/' filename.txt

But if I search for ID 45, all the entries which has 45 anywhere in their ID will be shown
*45* 
How to avoid that?
Basically, I want to search for exact match

Comment: Have you tried `awk`?

Comment: Have you tried `grep` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash search for string in each line of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695916/bash-search-for-string-in-each-line-of-file)

Comment: I don't know how to effectivel use awk,grep in this context. Please help

Comment: Here ya go buddy, this will teach you how to be effective with awk: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions: 
 awk -F"|" '$2 ~/4524/{print $2}' file 
 4524
 awk -F"|" '$2 ~/4524/' file 
 1|4524|John Blake|New York|11505

Comment: How to do it if the ID to be searched was stored in a variable 'var' ?
I tried these. Butdidn't work
awk -F"|" '$2 ~/$var/{print $2}' file
awk -F"|" '$2 ~/($var)/{print $2}' file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search e.g. for id 4524 you may use this one-liner:

```
tail -n+2 my_file |
    while read -r line; do
        no=`echo "$line" | cut -d'|' -f2`
        if [ "$no" -eq 4524 ]; then
            echo "$line"
        fi
    done
```

There are probably more sophisticated solution for it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk

awk '$1 ~/4524/' filename.txt

where $1 shows 2nd column in your file, 4524 shows the specific id which you can change & filename.txt is the name of your file which contain the records.

Comment: How to do it if the ID to be searched was stored in a variable 'var' ?
I tried these. Butdidn't work
awk -F"|" '$2 ~/$var/{print $2}' file
awk -F"|" '$2 ~/($var)/{print $2}' file